# Python code running well independently, but throwing traceback error while executing the same through excel VBA button trigger

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32, traceback

I am trying to call a python file from VBA enabled button, which uses pywin32 to get data from .xlsm file where the button was triggered. It performs computations on certain data and then writes back an output onto the same .xlsm file.

Following is the VBA code that I am using

```
python_exe_path = """C:\Users\Userprofile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"""
Current_Working_Dir = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Python_script_file = "\file_name.py"

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
errorCode = objShell.Run(Pythonexe & Current_Working_Dir & Python_script_file, waitOnReturn, windowStyle)
```

My Python code stops running at this line where the sheet name is being assigned

```
#Assigning Path of xlsm
raw_data_path = 'path of xlsm file

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(raw_data_path)

#Assigning sheet names
sheet= xlwb.Worksheets('sheet1')
```

Running the py file from VBA shell call enabled button lead to the code aborting and closing.
Following are the screenshots that show the issue:

[image: traceback error]

The reason I am not able to decipher this is issue is because when I run the .py file exclusively without the VBA button trigger, it performs perfectly...

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The traceback indicates that `xlwb.Worksheets('User Inputs')` failed because `xlwb` is `None`. So the next step is find out why it's `None`. Hypothesis: `raw_data_path` does not contain the correct path to the Workbook from the current working directory.

Comment: raw_data_path has the path correctly stored. Else the python script would not function idependently either and throw the same error

Comment: Since `'User Inputs'` is a relative path (does Excel automatically append `.xls`?), it won't work if VBA is running in a different current working directory. You can test that hypothesis by showing the working directory and path in an alert, or make it irrelevant by ensuring the code uses an absolute path, or investigate other ways that `xlApp.Workbooks.Open()` can fail.

Comment: What happpens if DisplayAlerts=True?